# Modelica pumps spinning at zero load

Tags: modelica

I have a question for the pump experts.
I have two pumps in parallel, connected in modelica to pressure sources as boundaries, in such a way that both pumps are connected downstream to the same sink, but they have separate volume sources.

The control strategy is as follows. One pump turns on, whilst the other is off, and after 90 seconds, with a filter and smooth ramp, like in a three ways valve, the second pump starts to spin on, and the first one is shut down.

My question in fact is, why if power and torque signals in the pumps go down or up to or from zero, then the speed in both pumps is not zero, in any of the cases, either when pump 1 is on and 2 off and vice versa? There is a sort of drag or resistance that pulls the pump and makes it spin even though there is not load or torque demand?

Looking forward to your answer.

Victor

Comment: Could you please post the code for your model?

Comment: I can share a picture of the model should it is useful, as the model was built up in IGNITE, it's ok? @ReneJustNielsen

Comment: I don't think a picture will provide much additional information. If you have the pumps connected in Modelica, you must have an .mo file (or be able to generate one) with a layout like this one [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ojPn4YxnI9NFBKQWdyczVPbEk/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ojPn4YxnI9NFBKQWdyczVPbEk/view?usp=sharing) for example it would be usefull to see your pump curves, boundary values, parameters etc. to understand your problem.

Comment: It's a bit difficult getting code in Ignite, anyway, I think I sorted my problem out myself.
Then, though there is not volume flow, as the dP in the pump (which when the pump is off, is defined by the difference between sources as sinks) is not zero, and dP is directly proportional to pump rpm, that is the reason why rpm can't be zero even when the torque demand is zero.

Comment: Ok. Great that you found a solution. Regards Rene Just Nielsen